# Differences between tr1::shared_ptr and boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, tr1

Are there any difference between `tr1::shared_ptr` and `boost::shared_ptr`? If so, what?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, the documentation of boost shared_ptr says:

> This implementation conforms to the
>   TR1 specification, with the only
>   exception that it resides in namespace
>   boost instead of std::tr1.

Comment: Ah. So, there's one difference.

Comment: The implementations may differ while still conforming; Notably `boost::shared_ptr`'s dereferencing operators use `Boost.Assert` to check for NULL (i.e. emptiness) before performing the dereference; while `libc++`'s `std::shared_ptr` has no such check.  In the case you hit this error at runtime, one will mean an assertion failure, the other a segmentation fault (probably).