# Difference between boost::shared_ptr and std::shared_ptr from the standard <memory> file

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I was wondering if there are any differences between the `boost::shared_ptr` and the `std::shared_ptr` found in the standard `<memory>` file.

Comment: This would depend on your implementation.

Comment: @robert Can they be used interchangeably? I am trying to implement this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559412/how-to-store-different-data-types-in-one-list-c/3560884#3560884

Comment: @P.R. - `std::shared_ptr` is the C++0x form of `tr1::shared_ptr`, and boost's `shared_ptr` should behave the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831572/differences-between-tr1shared-ptr-and-boostshared-ptr

Comment: Thanks :). I'll go ahead and do some test runs.

Comment: In light of that question, @Birryree, I guess this question really asks whether C++0x makes any changes to shared_ptr, or whether it's identical to the one from TR1.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy - Guess I'll have to do an answer. :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between different flavours of shared_ptr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086798/differences-between-different-flavours-of-shared-ptr)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between different flavours of shared\_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086798/differences-between-different-flavours-of-shared-ptr)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` is the C++0x form of `tr1::shared_ptr`, and boost's `boost::shared_ptr` should behave the same.

However, `std::shared_ptr`, in an implementation that conforms to C++0x standard, should/might have more convenience behavior on the `shared_ptr` class, as described in the following links:

- [Differences between different flavours of shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086798/differences-between-different-flavours-of-shared-ptr)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#General-purpose_smart_pointers

> The `shared_ptr` is a reference-counted pointer that acts as much as possible like a regular C++ data pointer. The TR1 implementation lacked certain pointer features such as aliasing and pointer arithmetic, but the C++0x version will add these.

- [November 2010 Working Draft of C++0x](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3225.pdf)

Though from a quick cursory glance, I do not see `operator+` and similar arithmetic operations on the `shared_ptr` type.

Comment: Hi, I'm a little confused by all these links and additional information.   So, in all, what you mean is that `std::shared_ptr` and `boost::shared_ptr` behaves *the same*. Right?