# Mixing boost smart pointers and C++11 smart pointers in boost::signals2

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have an application which uses `boost::signals2` to communicate between components. I am trying to use it's automatic connection management features through `slot_type(...).track(weak_ptr)`.

**The problem:**

Throughout my program, `std::shared_ptr` is used. `.track` expects a `boost::weak_ptr`, and I am providing an `std::weak_ptr`.

**Here's the exact error I'm getting:**

```
cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::weak_ptr<_Ty>' to 'const boost::weak_ptr<void> &'
```

Is there a workaround for this? Or have I misunderstood the problem?

Comment: Related/possibly helpful: [cohabitation of boost::shared_ptr and std::shared_ptr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314967/cohabitation-of-boostshared-ptr-and-stdshared-ptr)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution, and it was to use `.track_foreign` instead of `.track`. It allows the use of C++11 smart pointers in place of the boost smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

To the eyes of C++, and the compiler, `std::weak_ptr` and `boost::weak_ptr` are two completely different classes that has nothing in common. Therefore, when you are using `boost::signals2` I'd suggest you to stick with `boost::weak_ptr`.

Comment: Just found a solution, but yes that was what I was thinking too. Writing up my answer now.