# Boost signals2 and std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals2

Is it possible to configure (at compile time) `boost::signals2` to use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `boost::shared_ptr`, for e.g. in calls like `boost::signals2::deconstruct`?

I am using boost 1.68

Comment: Please make sure to include the c++ tag for C++ questions, so that more users will see the question.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking into it, I can guess that the answer will be "no" since changing it would change the interface types, which invites all manner of ODR violations and, thereby, hairy bugs.

However, if you *have* to bridge the divide, you *can* sometimes your std::shared_ptr inside a boost::shared_ptr (or vice versa): [Cohabitation of boost::shared_ptr and std::shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314967/cohabitation-of-boostshared-ptr-and-stdshared-ptr)